# Postgres parse array/json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have the following rows in the table `src` where one of the attributes is an array of JSONs.

Attribute:

```
[{"key": "Tag", "value": "myTagValue"}, {"key": "Brand", "value": "myBrandValue"}]
[{"key": "Tag", "value": "myTagValue"}, {"key": "Brand", "value": "myBrandOtherValue"}, {"key": "Test", "value": "123"}]
```

How does one select the `Brand`?

Expected output:

```
Brand
-----
myBrandValue
myBrandOtherValue

(2 rows affected)
```

I was thinking of using `json_to_recordset(json)` function, but the attribute can have `N` different values (jsons).

Comment: Is this an array of JSON `json[]` or is this a JSON array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=253d24cfc771ec403ad8c0f3084c5e6b)

```
SELECT
    elems.value ->> 'value'              -- 3
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata) elems   -- 1 
WHERE elems.value ->> 'key' = 'Brand'    -- 2
```

1. Extract all array elements into one row per JSON element
2. Filter the JSON elements by `key = Brand`
3. Return `value`